# After modifcating an "img.png", the img src='img.png' tag continues getting the older "img.png"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an image "img.png" with content 'A', the user changes the content of this img to 'B'. All via Ajax. When I try to put this "img.png" in some img src tag it shows me the 'A' content instead of the 'B', but when I reload the page, he shows me the 'B' correctly.
OBS:Obviously that is a simplified and summed up case, but some very similar is happening to me. Please help.

Comment: browser cache...unless the url changes somehow, or you output the image originally with appropriate headers, the browser is free to cache the image and see "ah, I'm fetching /images/kittens.jpg, and I already fetched that earlier, so I won't bother fetching a new copy".

Comment: I imagined something like that. Can you show me some solution changing the header?

Answer (score -1):

As the images are "re-using" the same URL, your logic should also append a query string with a versioning number or timestamp to the image URL.  Also simplified:

```
timestamp = Date.now();

img.src = sitename="/image.png?"+ timestamp;
```

Comment: i dont think breaking cacheing is a great idea.

Comment: I might agree; neither is using the same URL for different images, but I didn't write the use-case here. ;)

Comment: a common approach is to add a version number, you can update when the image changes. file name does not need to change, caching still works

Comment: Incidentally, it won't *completely* break caching.  As long as the image doesn't get changed again, most caches should be fine with "image.png?123456789" ...

Comment: your time changes so yes it wold

Comment: No, it only changes if the image changes.  We do the same thing with stylesheets and JavaScript.  "/js/script.js?20160804a" is perfectly cacheable.

Comment: your not saving that as the new name, or are you?

Comment: yes but your using js so the timestamp would be new on every single load

Comment: The JS is there as an example of how the OP would change the img src.  I'm not suggesting that the page *itself* change the img src without input from the user ... that would be, um, silly.  I guess I could write it in Python, PHP, C or sh if that'd make you feel better :-)

Comment: so your solution, is not the code you actually posted, well that's um, silly

Comment: My solution is to have his logic add a timestamp when the image is changed by the user.  There's nothing silly about that.  It's standard practice to avoid caching in situations just like this.

Comment: Please, show me the solution. I tried with the ".png?...", but didn't worked

Comment: Just .png? ... there must be something else after it.  Example, I have a PHB with an older system.  He gets email from the marketroid department and looks at it and "last month's magazine" shows up where the image SRC is set to "magazine_cover.jpg".  I go and yell at the marketing guys, "set a query string on that image SRC attribute" ... they change it to "magazine_cover.jpg?082016" and send a new test copy and the PHB is happy.  Without seeing code, I can't fix it ... besides, the PHB has something else that needs fixing.  This ain't rocket science, if you can write AJAX, you can do this.